# How to derive from a base class when the base initializer is available only through a helper function?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, inheritance, factory-method

This is a general Object Oriented Programming question:

Suppose I am given a base class B:

```
class B {
   // member functions
}
```

and suppose I am told to create an instance of B through the following factory method:

```
B createB(/* arguments */) {
   b = ...
   return b;
}
```

Now, the problem is that I need to derive from B but how am I going to initialize it as createB() does?:

```
class D : B {
   D() {
      /* need to use createB() to 
         initialize the base because 
         no equivalent constructor
         exists. */
   }
}
```

Comment: I would say we need to develop proper constructor for B.

Factory method is helpful when we are creating an object of required (not known on compile time) type, but here we are creating "exact" type and  constructor is the function specially intended for it.

BTW, in COM there is no inheritance - all objects are created by CoCreateInstance factory method accepting GUID.

Answer (score 0):

Using factory methods is in many aspects much better than just directly calling constructors. Once you've chosen using factory methods, you should stick to this approach for all the derived class -  otherwise you violate the basic reason for why the factory methods have been introduced: separate the object creation from object usage.

Hence, instead of solving the issue of accessing the factory method for class `B` from the constructor of class `D`, think about creating a factory method also for the class `D`. Or even better: create a common factory method `B createB(arguments)` which decides itself what type it creates and returns.